# How to determine if request will result in a successful HTTP request?

Tags: 6, hooks

Two part question here.

What is the proper way in a module to determine if a page request is resulting in a HTTP 200 OK?  Looking through `static $stored_headers` for a 30x/40x/50x seems wrong.

What is the earliest hook that you can reliably do this from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was developing the code for [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords), I used the following code, to verify if Drupal was serving an error page:

```
  $headers = drupal_get_headers();

  if (preg_match('@HTTP/1\.[01]\x20+403@', $headers)) {
    return array('type' => NODEWORDS_TYPE_ERRORPAGE, 'id' => 403);
  }

  if (preg_match('@HTTP/1\.[01]\x20+404@', $headers)) {
    return array('type' => NODEWORDS_TYPE_ERRORPAGE, 'id' => 404);
  }
```

The function containing that code is called from `nodewords_preprocess_page()`, the implementation of `hook_preprocess_page()`.

Comment: Thanks.  This is essentially what I am doing.  It just doesn't seem "right".

Comment: It's the only way I know of, as the path is not changed, when Drupal returns an error page. Suppose the user try to access http://example.com/404, when that page doesn't exist; Drupal shows the error page, but the URL the user would see is still the same.