# How to check if the current page is a 404 error from a module/template?

Tags: http-request

How to check, in D7, if the current page is returning a 404 error from a module/template?

Comment: Related question for Drupal 6: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10259/how-to-determine-if-request-will-result-in-a-successful-http-request

Comment: Also related to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-a-module-detect-when-drupal-is-outputting-the-access-denied-page/585#585

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Drupal 7, you can use [`drupal_get_http_header()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_http_header/7).

In the template.php file, use this code.

```
$status = drupal_get_http_header("status");
if ($status === '404 Not Found'){
  // Do something.
}
```

In Drupal 8, you can use the following code in a hook.

```
$route_name = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('_route');
if ('system.404' === $route_name) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Comment: What function does this code go in, within template.php?

Comment: You can place this code inside template_preprocess_page(&$variables)

Comment: This can also be implemented in hook_exit()

Comment: If you're looking to handle a 403, you can use: `if ($status == '403 Forbidden') { /* ... do stuff ... */ }`

Comment: or if you just want the status code, you can do: `$status_code = drupal_substr($status,0,3);`

Comment: Note: the solution for Drupal 8 based on the `system.404` route does not work if you've specified a node page as your 404 page in *Configuration > System > Basic site settings* . See @Gervase' answer for a solution that works when you either have or do not have a custom 404 page specified.

Answer (score 18):

Drupal 8.2.x:

Unfortunately, drupal_get_http_header("status") doesn't work any more.

Try:

```
$status = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception');
if ($status && $status->getStatusCode() == 404){

}
```

There is a discussion of this here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1969270

Comment: This is *just what I was looking for!*   <3

Comment: Careful though - the object retruned there might not have a `getStatusCode` function.

Comment: It ends my endless search and trying.

Comment: Finally, the endless search finds its rest!

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way to detect Access Denied (403) and Page Not Found (404) in Drupal 7.

```
// get the menu router item for the current page
$router_item = menu_get_item();

// if there is no router item, this page is not found
$is_page_not_found_404 = empty($router_item);

// if 'access' is empty for the router item, access is denied
$is_access_denied_403 = empty($router_item['access']);
```

Comment: `$router_item` won't be empty if the `site_404` variable is set to a node path, so additional checks would be needed.

Comment: menu_get_item, bit expensive call per page no?