# How do I redirect access denied to front page?

Tags: 7, redirection, authentication-authorization

I asked this a while back and got nowhere. Sorry for the repost but it needs to be resolved (somehow).

If a visitor types in a URL for which they are not authorized, I do -not- want them to see a 403 page. I just want them to be redirected to the site home page.

I entered...

```
<front>
```

...in the 403 field under admin/config/system/site-information but that apparently does nothing. We're using LoginToboggan which (I think) overrides this.

How can I do this?

TIA,

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `<front>` try using `node` or 'home page path' if you have customized home page.

...in the 403 field under admin/config/system/site-information.

Ref: [Redirect 404 errors to home page?](https://www.drupal.org/node/178653)

Comment: "node" is the default front page but in my experience it is usually changed to something else.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how it usually changed. I verified this myself and it worked!!

Comment: Technically it works but if the website is not using "node" as the home page then you will be directing people to the wrong page. The "node" page is just a listing of content that has been promoted to front page but a large number of sites have home page requirements that don't match the "node" page so they implement a more custom home page using an individual node page, panels, an empty page full of blocks, etc. For more information see https://www.drupal.org/node/265172

Comment: They could replace "node" in your answer with whatever they have the home page configured to, however that isn't ideal and won't work in all possible cases if the home page is more dynamic, for example different home pages for different user roles.

Comment: Since in the actual question jchwebdev was trying to achieve this through back-end site configuration, I suggested to use node. If your home pages are dynamic, then you have a different solution through code. Identify if page is 404 or 403 in template.php and redirect users accordingly.

Ref: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23237/how-to-check-if-current-page-is-404#

Comment: Dynamic home pages are usually not custom coded but configured via the UI so this should also be solveable via the UI. I think your answer to configure a specific URL is valid I just don't think it should be "node" but "whatever you set the home page path to be".

Comment: Yes. You're right indeed!! But I would love to know if there is a UI configuration method / module to achieve this. Let me know if you are aware. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22650/discussion-between-immanuel-paul-and-rooby).

Comment: FWIW 'node' does not work well. It actually -does- redirect to the front page BUT, the page title in the browser tab remains 'Access Denied' AND the message 'no front page content defined yet' appears at bottom.