# Hide title if 404 error

Tags: 8, theming, http-request

I have a custom 404 error page, and I just want a quick module that hides the 404 page title, if the user arrives at a 404 error.

I've found a D7 function that looks like it would work, checking for '404 Not Found' in the http header, and adding a class that I can target with CSS. But I'm not sure how I'd do something like this for D8.

Here's what I've got:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $headers = drupal_get_http_header();

  if (isset($headers['status']) && $headers['status'] == '404 Not Found') {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'page-404';
  }
}
```

Comment: One way to do this is add twig template suggestions for a 404 response, create that twig file and not print the region that normally has the title block. I’m on mobile so o have no code in front of me.

Comment: Hiding the title with CSS isn't hiding it from search engines or screen readers.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need a custom module for something like this...
This should be as easy as:

1. Go to `Configuration -> System -> Basic Site Settings`, get the page URL you have for the 404 page.
2. Go to `Structure -> Block Layout`, edit the 'Page Title' block, and exclude it under the `Visibility` section, by page URL from step1.

Comment: already tried. it doesn't work. because the page doesn't load the 404 page URL. It simply replaces expected content with the 404 content. If I go to website.com/randompagename , it drops in the 404 error, but still has the same url.

Comment: You can do it this way in UI, but you need a contrib module for the visibility condition: https://www.drupal.org/project/block_in_page_not_found

Comment: @4k4 ..ah! dang it! I know the module, but forgot that it has a 'negate' option! That did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function modulename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $status = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception');
  if($status && $status->getStatusCode() == '404') {
    if(!$variables['attributes']) {
      $variables['attributes'] = new Attribute();
    }
    $variables['attributes']->addClass('page-404');
  }
}
```

credits go to: [How to check if the current page is a 404 error from a module/template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23237/how-to-check-if-the-current-page-is-a-404-error-from-a-module-template)